# Duplication of results when using FULL OUTER JOIN / COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #datesX
    (
    [Name] [varchar] (8) NULL
    , [MarriedDate] datetime NULL
    , [HappyScoreX] [int] NULL
    ) 
INSERT INTO #datesX 
    values 
     ('TIM', null, 20),
     ('RAJ', '01 jan 2012', 20),
     ('PAUL', '01 jan 1960', 20)


CREATE TABLE #datesY
    (
    [Name] [varchar] (8) NULL
    , [FirstSprogDate] datetime NULL
    , [HappyScoreY] [int] NULL
    ) 
INSERT INTO #datesY 
    values 
     ('TIM', '01 jan 1995', 20),
     ('RAJ', '20 JUN 2013', 20),
     ('JASE', null, 20),
     ('PAUL', '01 jan 1970', 20)


CREATE TABLE #datesZ
    (
    [Name] [varchar] (8) NULL
    , [FoundGodDate] datetime NULL
    , [HappyScoreZ] [int] NULL
    ) 
INSERT INTO #datesZ 
    values 
     ('TIM', null, 20),
     ('RAJ', null, 20),
     ('JASE', '01 DEC 2012', 20),
     ('PAUL', '01 jan 1970', 20)




SELECT 
        [Name] = COALESCE(x.Name, y.Name, z.Name), 
        x.[MarriedDate],
        y.[FirstSprogDate],
        z.[FoundGodDate],
        [HappyScoreX] = SUM(ISNULL(x.[HappyScoreX],0.0)),
        [HappyScoreY] = SUM(ISNULL(y.[HappyScoreY],0.0)),
        [HappyScoreZ] = SUM(ISNULL(z.[HappyScoreZ],0.0))
FROM 
        #datesX x
        FULL OUTER JOIN #datesY y ON
                x.Name = y.Name 
        FULL OUTER JOIN #datesZ z ON
                x.Name = z.Name 
GROUP BY
        COALESCE(x.Name, y.Name, z.Name), 
        x.[MarriedDate],
        y.[FirstSprogDate],
        z.[FoundGodDate]
```

I can sort of see why the record for `JASE` is being duplicated - how do I amend the query so that `JASE` only has one record ?

Comment: And wich record do you want?, they are not exact duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this join instead:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN #datesY y ON
       x.Name = y.Name 
FULL OUTER JOIN #datesZ z ON
       coalesce(x.Name, y.name) = z.Name
```

Comment: excellent - colleague just showed me the same answer; so simple when you know how

Answer (score 1):

You want one row per name.  My advice is to build up the keys first, then go get the rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #nameKeys
(
  [Name] varchar(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO #nameKeys ([Name])
SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM #datesX WHERE [Name] is not null
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM #datesYY WHERE [Name] is not null
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM #datesZ WHERE [Name] is not null


--Then later...

FROM
  #nameKeys n
  LEFT JOIN #datesX x ON n.[Name] = x.[Name]
  LEFT JOIN #datesY y ON n.[Name] = y.[Name]
  LEFT JOIN #datesZ z ON n.[Name] = z.[Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble you have is that you have two `FULL OUTER JOINS` on #datesX. Since there is no row in #datesX for `JASE` you have rows you return rows from both Y and Z tables but your last Full outer sepcifies that you should match X.Name to Z.Name. The following code will get you what you want (I think|)

```
SELECT 
        [Name] = COALESCE(x.Name, y.Name, z.Name), 
        x.[MarriedDate],
        y.[FirstSprogDate],
        z.[FoundGodDate],
        [HappyScoreX] = SUM(ISNULL(x.[HappyScoreX],0.0)),
        [HappyScoreY] = SUM(ISNULL(y.[HappyScoreY],0.0)),
        [HappyScoreZ] = SUM(ISNULL(z.[HappyScoreZ],0.0))
FROM 
        #datesX x
        FULL OUTER JOIN #datesY y ON
                x.Name = y.Name 
        FULL OUTER JOIN #datesZ z ON
                z.Name = COALESCE(x.Name, y.Name)
GROUP BY
        COALESCE(x.Name, y.Name, z.Name), 
        x.[MarriedDate],
        y.[FirstSprogDate],
        z.[FoundGodDate]
```

Answer (score 1):

To build upon David B's answer further it makes sense to use a `Common Table Expression`:

```
;WITH NameKeys
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM #datesX WHERE [Name] is not null
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM #datesYY WHERE [Name] is not null
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM #datesZ WHERE [Name] is not null
)
SELECT 
        n.[Name], 
        x.[MarriedDate],
        y.[FirstSprogDate],
        z.[FoundGodDate],
        [HappyScoreX] = SUM(ISNULL(x.[HappyScoreX],0.0)),
        [HappyScoreY] = SUM(ISNULL(y.[HappyScoreY],0.0)),
        [HappyScoreZ] = SUM(ISNULL(z.[HappyScoreZ],0.0))
FROM NameKeys n
LEFT JOIN #datesX x ON n.[Name] = x.[Name]
LEFT JOIN #datesY y ON n.[Name] = y.[Name]
LEFT JOIN #datesZ z ON n.[Name] = z.[Name]
```

Comment: +1 for valid alternative. t-clausen.dk solution is the most elegant.